# How do you identify rare items?

Tags: diablo-iii

I found a yellow Rare item, and it is unidentified. How do I reveal the properties of the weapon? I tried going to Deckard Cain (as you did in the previous 2 games), but he didn't have the option of identifying my items.

Comment: you answer this your self in 36 sec O_o

Comment: Just sharing something I learned that wasn't immediately obvious (at least to me; maybe it's just the lack of sleep talking). http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: It is also answered by the tooltip on the rare item ingame!

Comment: ah they posted it as *rare* items, thats why I couldn't find it, sorry about that.  Closing :)

Comment: After playing again last night and finding another Rare... the hint in the tooltip is so small that I'm not terribly surprised I missed it. Judging by the upvotes, others are having this problem too.

Comment: I searched here to find the answer, because the tooltip is quite tiny. I'm quite glad dpatchery asked and answered the question. :-)

Comment: If you're coming from Diablo 2, you're probably expecting to need a  scroll. I was wondering the same thing, I never thought about checking the tooltip, so I think its a legitimate question and at least 1000 others already found so as well

Comment: I totally missed the tooltip as well. +1

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### As of Patch 2.0.1, the below answer is out of date.

Rare items no longer need to be identified. Legendary items still do, though. Just right click them to reveal which item you've discovered.

---

Just right click the item. A short cast bar animation will appear and you'll identify the item yourself, no need to go anywhere.

This is explained in-game by the small bar at the bottom of the tooltip, but its easy to miss.

[image: Unidentified Item]

Comment: I felt stupid when I figured this out, since it took me a good half hour to think to just try equipping it. Just wanted this out there for visibility.

Comment: @Downvoter - Care to explain? Any suggestions to improve the answer?

Comment: please update your answer, with the latest update, rares now auto identify, only legendaries require the old style identifications.

Answer (score 8):

Right click on it.  It will identify in a few seconds.

Comment: This could easily have been just a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound Comments are for information that *doesn't answer the question*.  The fact that the question can be answered by a single sentence does not mean it should be a comment (nor that it is low quality and deserves a downvote).

Comment: @Ramhound "[When shouldn't I comment? Comments are not recommended for any of the following:Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one)](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 6):

As of patch 1.0.8, there is a new option to identify all your unidentified objects in one (long) click:

> Players can now identify all items in their inventory by speaking to Deckard Cain or by using the Book of Cain that can be found near the shared stash in all Acts

[Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/9425564/public-test-realm-patch-108-notes-updated-418-4-18-2013#general)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could go into town, in between the pub place and Cain's home is a book. Click on it and it will identify your unidentified items.

Comment: This is just repeating what others have said already.