# What should I do with an unidentified item?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you identify rare items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66352/how-do-you-identify-rare-items)

I have looted a rare sword, but who do I take it to, to get identified?  I cannot view any stats about it or sell it until I identify this item.