# Is there any limitation as to which character can identify an item in Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

During one of the quests, my co-op partner( with level 10 Demon Hunter as the character) was rewarded with a [rare item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flsuy.jpg). Apparently he wasn't able to identify the item(there was no option for him to do so) while my character, a level 12 Monk was able to identify the item.

Why was this is so? Is there any restriction that only particular characters at particular levls can identify items?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

He wasn't able to identify the item because he didn't know how to do so properly.

[All characters can identify all rare items.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66352/how-do-you-identify-rare-items)

Comment: And effectively for free.