# How to identify unidentified items in Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you identify rare items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66352/how-do-you-identify-rare-items)

In Diablo 2 we use scrolls of identification. What do we use in diablo III, since Cain can no longer do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You right click on the item you wish to identify.