# How do I identify a item in Diablo 3 on console?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I found a legendary bracer item, unidentified. It seems unidentified items are incredibly rare, as this is the first one I have encountered despite being somewhat far in.

It says "*press x to identify*", but pressing x does not identify it. Is this a bug? Do I need to get further in the game to unlock some identification skill?

This is for the Xbox360. *edited in answer to own question* you hold down the X and wait for a bar to fill.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you identify rare items?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66352/how-do-you-identify-rare-items)

Comment: @P1raten, while ambiguously the same question, this question is directed at console, and the other question is directed at computer. While identical features, the method taken is technically different, and as such the duplicate in no way answers this question.

Answer (score 11):

On console, the identification tool-tip is slightly misleading.

While it says "press X", **you actually have to hold X**. While you hold X, a progress bar will appear on the item. Once the bar fills up, the item will be identified.

Comment: While the OP seems to be on Xbox, it might be worth noting that on PS4 you simply press square (unless we want yet another "how do I identify" question to pop up for that console). While it also has a progress bar appear, you don't have to hold the button down.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, so simple, just needed to HOLD DOWN X, rather then "pressing it" like it said on the screen.

Comment: Considering my console lacks internet access at the moment, it's probably not the latest patch thus lacks this book. Well legendary items are rare enough there is no point to that right now.

Answer (score 0):

To complete answer, I would add that you can now (it's been quite a long time by now) identify multiple items together.

In order to do that, you have to go back to the town of the act you're in, and try to find the [Book of Cain](https://diablo.fandom.com/wiki/Book_of_Cain_(Diablo_III)). It is usually near your chest and the armory.

As for the individual identify, you have to hold X while facing the book.